# Service layer unit testing spring boot

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing

I want to test my service layer but stuck with an error.
I have `Company` entity and createCompany method in my service

```
    public Company createCompany(String name) {
        Optional<Company> existingCompany = companyRepository.findCompanyByName(name);
        if (existingCompany.isPresent()) {
            log.error("Company with name {} already exists", name);
            throw new ValidationException("Company with name " + name + " already exists");
        } else {
            return companyRepository.save(new Company(UUID.randomUUID(), name, new HashSet<>()));
        }
    }
```

Here's my test:

```
    @Test
    public void whenCreateCompany_thenReturnCompany() {
        // prepare
        Company company = new Company();
        when(companyRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(company);

        // testing
        Company createdCompany = companyService.createCompany("name");

        // validate
        verify(companyRepository).save(company);
    }
```

But when I run test, I get an error

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
companyRepository.save(
    Company(id=null, name=null)
);
Actual invocations have different arguments:
companyRepository.findCompanyByName(
    "name"
);

companyRepository.save(
    Company(id=f7cf1525-0dc4-4c27-a9af-693e2a295437, name=name)
);
```

How to test the service level correctly?

Comment: Your verify line is doing nothing useful. You should at least check if createdCompany is the same as company that is returned by the save method. You probably can use an argument capture on save method to check if the "new Company" has the correct name. See, for example, https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `when` call to using `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any()` as parameter instead of your empty company object.

```
 when(companyRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(company);
```

In your code mockito expects your, in the test created, `company` object passed in the save method. But your manually `company` contains `id` and `name` as null values. But in your test you try to save a company with the `name=name` and a random generated uuid.

Update from comments:
You have to use any in the `verify` method, too.

```
verify(companyRepository).save(any());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same error. 
I think it's because I have the findCompanyByName method called in the createCompany method, but nowhere to check that it was called

Comment: Sorry! I am a little bit stupid :-)  You are absolutely right. The  `verify` still fails. There is also the company value with the `null` values used.
You can use `any()`in the `verify` too. Instead of the empty `company` object.
`verify(companyRepository).save(any());`